# take an arrary as input in golang

Tags: arrays, go

How am I goingt take an array as input in golang ?

```
func main() {
var inPut []float32
fmt.Printf("Input? ")
fmt.Scanf("%s", &inPut)
fmt.Println(inPut)

for _, value := range inPut {

    fmt.Print(value)
 }
}
```

I tried the code above and it doesn't give me the right answer, should I use another type of scanner ?

the input I want to take in is something like  [3.2 -6.77 42 -0.9]

Comment: Did you check the error and number of values scanned? See the [docs on scanning](https://golang.org/pkg/fmt/#hdr-Scanning)

Answer (score 0):

What you want to use are called [Slices](https://blog.golang.org/go-slices-usage-and-internals).

An array has a fixed size: `[n]T` is an array of `n` values of type `T`.

A slice, on the other hand, is a dynamically-sized, and flexible way of representing an array: `[]T` is a slice with elements of type `T`.

Slices are more common in the Go world.

```
package main

import "fmt"

func main() {
    len := 0
    fmt.Print("Enter the number of floats: ")
    fmt.Scanln(&len)
    input := make([]float64, len)
    for i := 0; i < len; i++ {
        fmt.Print("Enter a float: ")
        fmt.Scanf("%f", &input[i])
    }
    fmt.Println(input)
}
```

Output:

```
// Enter the number of floats: 4
// Enter a float: 3.2
// Enter a float: -6.77
// Enter a float: 42
// Enter a float: -0.9
// [3.2 -6.77 42 -0.9]
```

I hope this helps!